# Generating a certificate Thumbprint in C# (Implemented in Java)

Tags: c#, encryption, ssl-certificate

I have implemented a simple one liner that generates the certificate thumbprint in java

```
X509Certificate cert = readCertFromFile(path);   //I read the certificate here
byte[] digest = DigestUtils.sha256(cert.getEncoded());  //I calculate hash of the cert
```

I want to implement the same in C#. I have tried to use C#'s X509Certificate class to read the cert and generate the hash value but it is different from the value generated through java. Is there an implementation of java's X509Certificate.getEncoded() in C#? getEncoded() in java returns

> the encoded form of this certificate. It is assumed that each certificate type would have only a single form of encoding; for example, X.509 certificates would be encoded as ASN.1 DER.

I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to get the SHA-256 thumbprint of a certificate is

```
byte[] thumbprint = cert.GetCertHash(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

or, if you want the hex version:

```
string thumbprint = cert.GetCertHashString(HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
```

That's equivalent to the following code, which is more like the Java approach:

```
byte[] thumbprint = SHA256.HashData(cert.RawData);
```

the difference being that the [GetCertHash](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.getcerthash) routine doesn't need to make a copy of RawData value (which the property accessor does), so it's a bit more performant.